# How do I get JSON_OBJECT_AGG to use ints as object keys?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Given code like this:

```sql
JSON_OBJECT_AGG(company_id, JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(...)) AS company_info
```

I get JSON output like this:

```json
{"1234": {...}, "4321": {...}}
```

How do I get it to return the keys as ints instead of strings, so I'd get this:

```json
{1234: {...}, 4321: {...}}
```

The `company_id` already is an `INTEGER` to begin with, and I haven't found a way to tell JSON_OBJECT_AGG to keep it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. The JSON specification states that all keys must be string.

Converting the keys to integers should be done in your application logic after deserializing the returned database result.